# How to secure Angular JS from XSS atack?

Tags: angularjs, xss

I use `ng-repeat` for messages in chat:

```
ng-bind-html="message.message + getAttachmentTemplate(message.attachment)"
```

How I can to cut special symbols as JS, HTML and safe from XSS atack?
But I need to display HTML inside `getAttachmentTemplate`

Answer (score 0):

You need to include `angular-sanitize.js`, you can then load the `ngSanitize` module

`angular.module('app', ['ngSanitize']);`

You can then use the `$sanitize` service to sanitize your HTML snippets, see an example below:

```js
angular.module('expressionsEscaping', ['ngSanitize'])
  .controller('ExpressionsEscapingCtrl', function($scope, $sanitize) {
    $scope.msg = 'Hello, <b>World</b>!';
    $scope.safeMsg = $sanitize($scope.msg);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.0.2/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.0.2/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="expressionsEscaping" ng-controller="ExpressionsEscapingCtrl">
  <div class="container">
    <h2>Angular $sanitize demo</h2>

    <p ng-bind="msg"></p>
    <p ng-bind-html-unsafe="msg"></p>
    <p ng-bind-html="msg"></p>
    <p ng-bind-html-unsafe="safeMsg"></p>

    <div>Provided by <a onclick="window.open('stackoverflow.com')">Stack Overflow</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Like this: `ng-bind-html="message.message + getAttachmentTemplate($sanitize(message.attachment))"`

Comment: I get empty message when I use `$sanitize(message.message)`

Comment: Sorry the `$sanitize` call needs to be done in the controller

Comment: Reading the documentation `$sanitize` gets called by default for `ng-bind-html`, so you don't even need to call it. It may not cut tags, but it does prevent XSS injection.

Comment: yes, `ng-sanitize` only prevents against `XSS` attacks, it doesn't remove vanilla HTML links

Comment: Can I cut all tags for this part `ng-bind-html="message.message` somehow?